# How does the program work?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I was expecting the answer to the following program as 400 ... but why is it 120?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 10+10

int main()
{
    int a = N*N;
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

Comment: Because you're missing parentheses around the macro definition. Think about order of operations after the macro is expanded.

Answer (score 6):

`#define`'d constants are interpolated into the code literally, so effectively you had

```
int a = 10+10*10+10;
```

which is parsed as

```
(10 * 10) + 20 = 120;
```

The value of the `N` constant STAYS `10+10`. it's not evaluated/stored as `20`.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this `10+10*10+10`
Use this `#define N (10+10)` instead.

Comment: No, use something that's not a macro!

Comment: Use anything that is not a macro.

Answer (score 0):

In your program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 10+10

int main()
{
    int a = N*N;
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

The define will change N for he value of N and then make calculations, so:

```
int a = 10+10*10+10;

int a = 10+100+10;

a = 120;
```

What you need to do is:

```
#define N (10+10)
```

So, when you put parenthesis, the sum is calculated first, and the the multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

It becomes

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 10+10

int main()
{
    int a = 10+10*10+10;
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

The constant is 10+10, not 20. This get thrown in everywhere.